# Passing in options param for content_for method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I found that you can flush `content_for` looking at the Rails source. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb

**Rails Source:**

```
def content_for(name, content = nil, options = {}, &block)
  if content || block_given?
    if block_given?
      options = content if content
      content = capture(&block)
    end
    if content
      options[:flush] ? @view_flow.set(name, content) : @view_flow.append(name, content)
    end
    nil
  else
    @view_flow.get(name)
  end
end
```

I am trying to set `options[:flush] = true`, but am having some trouble. The `options[:flush]` is not evaluating to true in my code below.

**My code**:

```
content_for(affiliate_link_pos.to_sym, {:flush=>true}) do
  render page
end
```

**Edit**:
I have also tried passing a 3rd params (content), but I get `wrong number of argument error (3 for 2)`.

```
content_for(affiliate_link_pos.to_sym, "true",  {:flush=>true}) do
```

Comment: Just figured out why. I am on Rails 3.2.6 and content_for source is 3.2.8.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
content_for(affiliate_link_pos.to_sym, null, :flush=>true) do
  render page
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the source quoted in the OP's question is actually from Rails 4.  [Even in Rails 3.2.14, content_for does not accept any options.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.14/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for)

> ### **content_for**(name, content = nil, &block)
>
> Calling #content_for stores a block of markup in an identifier for later use. You can make subsequent calls to the stored content in other templates, helper modules or the layout by passing the identifier as an argument to content_for.

Comment: Link-only answers are discourage.